# Flexbox grow div to take up remaining height

Tags: html, css, sass

versions of this have been asked before and these questions helped me so far as to have a flex item that grows in height. However, it grows too much :)

Please see the code pen or the code here
https://codepen.io/surf-n-code/pen/wvwrbKW

Basically I have this Code

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box-1 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 60px;
}

.box-2 {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
}

.box-3 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="box box-0">Header - sticks to top</div>
  </header>

  <main class="full-height">
    <div class="nd_container">
      <div class="box box-1">content</div>
      <div class="box box-2">Flex grow</div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <div class="box box-4">Footer - stick to bottom</div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

I would expect the box-2 to increase in size just enough such that the footer sticks exactly to the bottom of the page. I do not want any scrolling due to the created whitespace.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: your flex parent should be body and set to min-height:100vh ... then you can imbricate again flex boxes. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gOYGJzw

Comment: Guys, thanks a lot!! Turns out, adding this is enough:
```body {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
  min-height:100vh;
}

.full-height {
  flex:1
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you expecting check out my answer.

**NOTE:CHECK OUT MY ANSWER IN FULL SCREEN MODE**

box-2 to increase in size just enough such that the footer sticks exactly to the bottom of the page.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
.nd_container {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.nd_container .box {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nd_container .box-1 {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 0 1 60px;
}

.nd_container .box-2 {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.box {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box.box-0 {
  background-color: #03a9f4;
  height: 100%;
}

.box.box-4 {
  background-color: #0c5460;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  flex: 0 1 155px;
}

main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

footer {
  flex: 0 1 155px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="box box-0">Header - sticks to top</div>
  </header>
  <main class="full-height">
    <div class="nd_container">
      <div class="box box-1">content</div>
      <div class="box box-2">Flex grow</div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div class="box box-4">Footer - stick to bottom</div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: no need of main , body is already here to do the job ;) , did you check my codepen yet https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gOYGJzw ? min-height is wiser than height here ;) , to avoid hidding content on small screens , such as tablets or mobile.

Comment: just now I saw, i updated my answer I just removed main div. @G-Cyr